# Parsing conditional statements

Tags: python, parsing

I've written a small utility in Python3 to help me copy my music collection from my NAS to a mobile device. The usefulness of this is that it will auto-convert flac files to ogg-vorbis (to save space) and also exclude some files based on their audio tags (i.e. artist, album, date, etc).

I'm not happy with the limited nature of the exclude feature and I want to improve it but I've hit a mental block and I'm looking for advice on how to proceed.

I would like the user to write an exclude file which will look something like this:

```
exclude {
    artist is "U2"

    artist is "Uriah Heep" {
        album is "Spellbinder"
        album is "Innocent Victim"
    }
}
```

This would translate to:

```
exclude if 
(artist = "U2") OR 
(artist = "Uriah Heep" AND (album = "Spellbinder" OR album = "Innocent Victim"))
```

There will be more conditionals such as sub-string matching and date ranges.

I've been checking out [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply) but I'm struggling with the concepts of how to parse this type of nested structure and also how to represent the resulting conditional so that I can execute it in code when applying the exclude filter during the copy operation.

Comment: General questions like this should go on programmers.sx.

Comment: If you don't mind using a non-custom format, there are libraries that can make parsing super simply.  For example, if you use HTML, you can use BeatifulSoup to easy parsing in one fell swoop (or, I guess, one fell soup).

Comment: @TomZych when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat yeah, we really need a way to flag postings to be moved to more sites.

Comment: @TomZych Please accept my apologies, it was my misunderstanding I will ask over at the programmer.sx.

Comment: Having now asked at programmers.sx I went to delete this post but it seems that's "frowned upon". Not sure if I should delete this one or not.

Comment: @TomZych: You're making an assertion about where a question goes that is not part of any policy, either here or on Programmers, that I know of.  You can find out more about *actual policy* by reading [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is **almost** a dict, why not just use JSON? To go one better, you chould use [Lucene Query Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html).

Comment: Ok thanks. Whilst the only user is likely to be me I did have the non-programmer in mind so was trying to keep the syntax simple and making no demands on knowledge of such formats.